# How to mock nltk.sent_tokenize?

Tags: unit-testing, nlp, pytest, nltk, pytest-mock

I want to mock out the output of nltk.sent_tokenize. I don't want to download the "punkt" or any other dictionary so I want to mock it out. I have tried many different strategies but nothing works. The actual nltk.sent_tokenize is called instead of the mock. What am I missing?
I am mocking out another function (B) called in the same script and that one runs successfully.

This is what I have tried:

```
[A.py]
import nltk
import B
.....
.....
x = nltk.sent_tokenize("something")
y = B() ### another function that I mock out


[test_A.py]
import sys
from unittest import mock
mock_nltk = mock.Mock()
mock_nltk.sent_tokenize.return_value = ["input"]
sys.modules["nltk"] = mock_nltk
......
......
def test_compute_list(return_value, mocker):

  mock_invoke = mocker.patch("B")
  mock_invoke.return_value = return_value
  assertion.....`
```

Comment: Hi, please provide a runnable example. I don't know what you put in `.......` so I can't test my idea without needless work.